# provisioning profile and app name mismatch

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, app-id

When I made the app ID for my app, for the identifier I put my app name as lowercase when my project is is uppercase. How could I use this with my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can changed the Product Name in the Build Settings of your Target (under your project file). That should populate the other fields required to make it work.

Comment: Didn't work. In the summary of the target it has my app name at the end of the identifier, but it is greyed out and it won't let me edit it, how do I change it?

Comment: In the info you'll see Bundle Identifier. that's the thing you have to change. However, usually that has a reference to the product name, like so: com.xxx.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}. Maybe you've changed it from the default at some point. If you change that to what you have in your profile it should work.